# Full screen and centre page advertisement take overs

Tags: usability, user-behavior, advertisement, case-studies

I'm looking for any stats on the effects of displaying full screen and centre page advertisement take overs on a webpage? - specifically on editorial style websites where the user is tasked with reading long form content.

Needing some ammunition to help build a case for not doing this.

Comment: *build a case for not doing this*. This will depend on your goals. If you want to make users happy, then there might be something. If your client or employer is looking to make a profit, good luck with that, this kind of advertisements are quite effective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great to see you are building a case for not doing this. From a User Experience perspective, here is some ammunition to help build your case:

1. [Norman Nielsen Group - The Most Hated Advertising Techniques](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/most-hated-advertising-techniques/): 95% of users (based on 605 respondents) said that their web experience was impacted "negatively" or "very negatively". I recommend reading the full article as it's an interesting read.
2. [Usage of Ad Blocking is on the rise](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2013/08/21/use-of-ad-blocking-is-on-the-rise/): Article which talks about users uptake in using ad blocking software. The article stated that the ad blocking trend was on the rise. There was varying numbers in regards to the current usage of ad blocking software.
3. [2014 Report - Adblocking goes mainstream](http://blog.pagefair.com/2014/adblocking-report/): Quick facts included that there are about 144 million active adblock users around the world, Adblock usage grew by nearly 70% between June 2013 – June 2014 and that Adblock usage is driven by young internet users. 41% of 18-29 year olds polled said they use adblock.

Though I wish there was more recent user research available, it's pretty clear that users really aren't happy with advertisements that take over a webpage based on the uptake in Ad Blocking software and the user research quoted.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This is a great start for me to build some sort of case against this decision.